# Extrinsic curvature of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature

I have a simple question. Curve in ${R}^{1,1}$ The 2 dimensional Minkowski space.
\begin{equation}
\gamma:[0,1] \longrightarrow R^{1,1},
\end{equation}
How can I calculate the extrinsic curvature of this curve seen as a 1 dimensional surface embedded in $R^{1,1}$?

Thanks!